How should I show that $F(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$ in this problem? (Please check my work.)
Show that the equation $\ddot{x}+(x^2-1)x^2\dot{x}+x^3=0$ has a unique periodic solution.
Here's my work:
Proof:
Consider the differential equation $\ddot{x}+(x^2-1)x^2\dot{x}+x^3=0$.
By theorem, the equation $\ddot{x}+f(x)\dot{x}+g(x)=0$ has a unique periodic solution if $f$ and $g$ are continuous, and
(i) $F(x)$ is an odd function;
(ii) $F(x)$ is zero only at $x=0, x=a, x=-a$, for some $a>0$;
(iii) $F(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$ monotonically for $x>a$;
(iv) $g(x)$ is an odd function, and $g(x)>0$ for $x>0$.
(Conditions (i) to (iii) imply that $f(x)$ is even, $f(0)<0$ and $f(x)>0$ for $x>a$.)
Let $f(x)=(x^2-1)x^2$ and $g(x)=x^3$ be continuous functions.
Then we have $F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(u)du$ for $x>0$.
This gives $F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}(u^2-1)u^2du\implies F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}(u^4-u^2)du\implies F(x)=[\frac{u^5}{5}-\frac{u^3}{3}]_{0}^{x}\implies F(x)=\frac{x^5}{5}-\frac{x^3}{3}$.
Note that $F(x)=\frac{x^5}{5}-\frac{x^3}{3}$ is an odd function because $F(-x)=\frac{(-x)^5}{5}-\frac{(-x)^3}{3}\implies F(-x)=\frac{-x^5}{5}-\frac{-x^3}{3}\implies F(-x)=-\frac{x^5}{5}+\frac{x^3}{3}$, which implies that $F(-x)=-F(x), \forall x$ in the domain of $f$.
Since $F(x)=\frac{x^5}{5}-\frac{x^3}{3}$ is an odd function, it follows that the first condition (i) is satisfied.
Let $F(x)=\frac{x^5}{5}-\frac{x^3}{3}=0$.
Then we have $F(x)=\frac{x^5}{5}-\frac{x^3}{3}=0\implies F(x)=\frac{3x^5}{15}-\frac{5x^3}{15}=0\implies \frac{3x^5-5x^3}{15}=0\implies 3x^5-5x^3=0\implies x^3(3x^2-5)=0$ where $x^3=0$ or $3x^2-5=0$ by the zero property.
This implies that $x=0$ and $x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{5}{3}}$ for $a=\sqrt{\frac{5}{3}}>0$.
Hence, the second condition is satisfied because $F(x)=\frac{x^5}{5}-\frac{x^3}{3}$ is zero only at $x=0, x=a, x=-a$, for some $a>0$.
Now we have $F'(x)=f(x)=(x^2-1)x^2>0$ for $x>1$, and so $F'(x)>0$ for $x>\sqrt{\frac{5}{3}}$, so the third condition is satisfied because $F(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$ monotonically for $x>a$.
Observe that $g(x)=x^3$ is an odd function because $g(-x)=(-x)^3=-(x^3)$, which implies that $g(-x)=-g(x), \forall x$ in the domain of $g$, and clearly $g(x)>0$ for $x>0$.
Thus, the fourth (last) condition is also satisfied because $g(x)$ is an odd function, and $g(x)>0$ for $x>0$.
From the work/proof above, I have doubt(s) about the (iii) third condition that I just showed, because I'm not 100% sure if the reason I've provided is true and accurate in order to show that $F(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$ monotonically for $x>a$ since I didn't provide a limit for $F(x)$. If what I did above for the (iii) third condition is wrong, then how should I provide a valid reason for this? Should I find the limit of $F(x)$ as $x$ approaches to $\infty$? And what's that limit then? Is it $\lim_{x\to\infty} F(x) =\infty$? Also, at the bottom, it says that the conditions (i) to (iii) imply that $f(x)$ is even, $f(0)<0$ and $f(x)>0$ for $x>a$, how should I provide a short proof for this in order to show/prove that $f(x)$ is an even function? And how does $f(0)<0$? Because $f(0)=(0^2-1)0^2=0$, so how does $f(0)<0$ when $f(0)=0$? Can anyone please check/verify/confirm to see if my work/proof is correct?


You forgot to define $F$ in the theorem you quote. Check more carefully Nonlinear Ordinary Differential Equations: An Introduction for Scientists and Engineers, by Dominic Jordan and Peter Smith, Theorem 11.4 p. 395: 4 lines above (on the same page) they defined
$$F(x)=∫_0^xf(u)du.$$
In (iii) you only checked monotonicity, but $\lim_∞F=∞$ is quite obvious:  as $x\to\infty$,$$F(x)=\int_0^x(u^4-u^2)du=\frac{x^5}5-\frac{x^3}3\to\infty.$$
$f(0)<0$ seems a typo: it should be $f(0)≤0$.
$f=F'$ is even because $F$ is odd.

